# IIS Redirect olddomain.com/en-us/ABC to newdomain.com/ABC

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'd like to put a redirect in web.config from **olddomain.com/en-us/abc/blahblah** to **newdomain.com/abc/blahblah**
Meaning in addition to the change of domain, the new URL doesn't have /en-us/, and everything else remain the same.
I picked up from here and there and came up with the following code, but it doesn't work. Could you help?

```
<rule name="Redirect New Site" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^/en-us/(.*)$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
  <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/abc/(.*)" />
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^olddomain.com/$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://newdomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Let FRT tell you if you wrote correct regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, I test it in my side. You can use the `<rule>` like below:

```
<rule name="redirectRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^en-us/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^olddomain$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://newdomain.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Here is the rule and test result in my side. The `<rule>` in my `web.config` is:

```
<rule name="redirectRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^en-us/(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^localhost:49293$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://newdomain.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

**Please note** my old domain is `localhost:49293`.

Then when I request the url `http://localhost:49293/en-us/Upload`, it will redirect to new url `http://newdomain.com/Upload`(without `en-us`).

[image]

============================**Update**============================

```
<rule name="redirectRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^en-us/abc/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^olddomain$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://newdomain.com/abc/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks Hury. Since I only want to redirect everything inside ONE particular folder (/abc/ in this case) to the new site while keeping everything else unchanged. I guess we'll need to declare the path info <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="..." /> somehow.

Comment: Hi @Michelle Could you please check if the update rule can meet your requirements ?